# Artifact with nine-patch textview background

Tags: android, textview, nine-patch

I have a `TextView` whose `layout_width` is set to `wrap_content` . I use a nine-patch image as background. TextView's content is periodically refreshed (I use thread which sleeps some time and then starts a handler). After few iterations there are some artifacts. I can see a part of text and background of some earlier message (it's width is bigger then the width of currently shown message). What could be the problem?

```
public void onCreate{
   ...
   helpField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.helpField);
   ...
}

private class PeriodicHelp extends Thread{
    private static final int SLEEP_TIME = 4000;
    private static final int NUM_HELP_PHRASES = 5;

    private String getHelp(){
        int pos = randomGenerator.nextInt(NUM_HELP_PHRASES);
        return helpPhrases[pos];
    }

    public void run(){
        int i = 0;
        while(true){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
                Log.d(TAG, "periodicHelp " + Integer.toString(i));
                i++; //used just for debugging
                mHandler.post(new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                        String help = getHelp();
                        helpField.setText(help);
                    }
                });
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I start my PeriodicHelp thread in `onStart()`

Comment: Are you changing the TextView contents and background too?

Comment: @LazyNinja Not background, just content

Comment: can you post some code ? how do you refresh your TextView ?

Comment: Okay then, we will need the relevant source code where you set the content.

Comment: What the range of the text length? Do you have very short and very long strings in helpPhrases?

Comment: @Lazy Ninja Shortest string has 7 characters and longest 17

Comment: Do you have any html formatting in your helpPhrases ?

Comment: @ben75 No, helpPhrases is a array of plain strings

Comment: @sinisha, just a guess; your nine patch could be incorrect. I see nothing wrong in your source code and layout-width set to wrap-content it was supposed to work. Could you add this to the xml TextView just to check something: android:padding="0dip"

Comment: @LazyNinja It doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manged to solve this problem. Here is the code

```
public void onCreate{
   ...
   helpField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.helpField);
   rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainView); //this RelativeLayout contains
                                                      //helpField  TextView     
   ...
}

private class PeriodicHelp extends Thread{
private static final int SLEEP_TIME = 4000;
private static final int NUM_HELP_PHRASES = 5;

private String getHelp(){
    int pos = randomGenerator.nextInt(NUM_HELP_PHRASES);
    return helpPhrases[pos];
}

public void run(){
    int i = 0;
    while(true){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
            Log.d(TAG, "periodicHelp " + Integer.toString(i));
            i++; //used just for debugging

            rl.postInvalidate();//THIS LINE FIX THE PROBLEM

            mHandler.post(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    String help = getHelp();
                    helpField.setText(help);
                }
            });
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

}